# My question is about sub-domain searching. I want to know the practical ways to find a website sub domain

Tags: python, dns

I want to search and find out the sub-domains for a particular website, for example, yahoo.com.

The Google search method (site:yahoo.com) is no more feasible because google throws captcha challenges.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you cannot do that easily and reliably.

The information you are looking for is stored in a DNS database called "zone". You could try to download the entire zone from the **authoritative** DNS server for the given domain, but this action (called zone transfer or AXFR) is often prohibited to everyone except secondary DNS servers. Actually that's the recommended DNS server setting.

Answer (score -1):

A simple who.is search will give you the DNS entries including A records associated with your domain. Another interesting way is to use [DNSRecon](https://github.com/darkoperator/dnsrecon).

Comment: tools like https://dnsdumpster.com/ has the option to search for the sub domains but i'm not able to get the logic to code in python

Comment: If its a one time activity, use the web version. If you want to repeat this process, better program it. You can schedule the program to email you the report as well. Possibility is endless.